# foreach loop throws null exception but object is not

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

i have mvc 4 master page where i want to display user specific menu
at the top of the page i am retrieving user data

```
@using Agenda_MVC.Engine
@{

    List<Format> ContactEvents = Agenda_MVC.Classes.Utility.GetContactEventFormats(User.Identity.Name);
}
```

but when i iterate through the list it throws null exception, on setting breakpoint the list is not null it has items.

```
@foreach (var ContactEvent in ContactEvents)
                {
                    <div class="@(ContactEvent.EventId == ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() ? "StaticMenuItemSelected" : "StaticMenuItem")">
                       @Html.ActionLink(ContactEvent.Name.Length > 15 ? ContactEvent.Name.Substring(0, 15) + "..." : ContactEvent.Name, "Agenda", "Portal", new { id = ContactEvent.EventId }, new { @title = ContactEvent.Name })
                    </div>    
                }
```

[image]

i dont know what i am doing wrong.

---

code for method is below i am retrieving it from a web service

```
public static List<Format> GetContactEventFormats(string ContactId)
{
    //List<Format> EventFormats = HttpContext.Current.Cache["EventFormats" + ContactId] as List<Format>;
    List<Format> EventFormats = HttpContext.Current.Session["EventFormats" + ContactId] as List<Format>;

    if (EventFormats == null)
    {
        EngineClient EngClient = Params.GetEngineClient();
        EventFormats = EngClient.GetContactEventFormats(ContactId);

        if (EventFormats != null && EventFormats.Count > 0)
        {
            //HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert("EventFormats" + ContactId, EventFormats, null, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30), TimeSpan.Zero);
            HttpContext.Current.Session["EventFormats" + ContactId] = EventFormats;
        }
    }

    return EventFormats == null ? new List<Format>() : EventFormats;
}
```

Comment: Post the code for ContactEvents. Maybe it is somehow lazy-initialized and returns null on first call, while returning non-null on second

Comment: Perhaps one of the 'ContactEvent' is 'null' and you get an exception because you call '.Name' and '.EventId'?

Comment: @mgttlinger none of the ContactEvent is null as the same code was working yesterday

Comment: @alex i have posted the code below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume `ContactEvent.Name` or `EventId` is null

You can check if both of these values are null in the `debugger` or by specifying a conditional before assigning the ContactEvent.Name to the `ActionLink` value.

```
<div class="@(ContactEvent.EventId == ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() ? "StaticMenuItemSelected" : "StaticMenuItem")">

                @if (ContactEvent.Name != null) {
                   @Html.ActionLink(ContactEvent.Name.Length > 15 ? ContactEvent.Name.Substring(0, 15) + "..." : ContactEvent.Name, "Agenda", "Portal", new { id = ContactEvent.EventId }, new { @title = ContactEvent.Name })
                }
                </div>
```

Comment: @user1799320 - also ensure ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] has a value.

Comment: none of the member of any object is null as its throwing exception before reaching that line, its throwing at the opening curly bracket.i can see all the values in the object and the object itself

Comment: @user1799320 - does ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] have a value?

Comment: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] was null thanks i changed it to <div class="@(ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"] != null && ContactEvent.EventId == ViewContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString() ? "StaticMenuItemSelected" : "StaticMenuItem")">

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ContactEvent object in your List during debugging.

Perhaps (probably) one or more fields e.g: `ContactEvent.EventId` or `ContactEvent.Name` are null.

Comment: no they are not i can confirm that when i drill down the object